# Spring Integration Default Response for Jms inboundGateway

Tags: spring-integration

Seeing the below `exception` when trying to send a default constructed response for `Jms inboundGateway` exception from the downstream call. We are extracting the `failedMessage` headers from the `ErrorMessage` and then setting the constructed response as `payload`. The `replyChannel` headers is matching with the initially logged `message header`

```
2023-01-26 20:34:32,623 [mqGatewayListenerContainer-1] WARN  o.s.m.c.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel - be776858594e7c79 Reply message received but the receiving thread has exited due to an exception while sending the request message: 

ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Failed to send or receive; nested exception is java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=NOT_PRINTED, headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@2454562d, b3=xxxxxxxxxxxx, nativeHeaders={}, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@2454562d, sourceTransacted=false, jms_correlationId=ID:xxxxxxxxxx, id=xxxxxxxxxx, jms_expiration=36000, timestamp=1674750867614}]
```

**Code:**

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.inboundGateway(mqGatewayListenerContainer)
                                .defaultReplyQueueName(replyQueue)
                                .replyChannel(mqReplyChannel)
                                .errorChannel(appErrorChannel)
                                .replyTimeout(mqReplyTimeoutSeconds * 1000L))
                        // log
                        .log(DEBUG, m -> "Request Headers: " + m.getHeaders() + ", Message: " + m.getPayload())
                        // transform with required response headers
                        .transform(Message.class, m -> MessageBuilder.withPayload(m.getPayload())
                                                                    .setHeader(ERROR_CHANNEL, m.getHeaders().get(ERROR_CHANNEL))
                                                                    .setHeader(REPLY_CHANNEL, m.getHeaders().get(REPLY_CHANNEL))
                                                                    .setHeader(CORRELATION_ID, m.getHeaders().get(MESSAGE_ID))
                                                                    .setHeader(EXPIRATION, mqReplyTimeoutSeconds * 1000L)
                                                                    .setHeader(MSG_HDR_SOURCE_TRANSACTED, transacted)
                                                                    .build())

    return IntegrationFlows.from(appErrorChannel())
                            .publishSubscribeChannel(
                                        pubSubSpec -> pubSubSpec.subscribe(sf -> sf.channel(globalErrorChannel))
                            .<MessagingException, Message<MessagingException>> 
transform(AppMessageUtil::getFailedMessageWithoutHeadersAsPayload)
                            .transform(p -> "Failure")
                            .get();

    public static Message<MessagingException> getFailedMessageAsPayload(final MessagingException messagingException) {
    
        var failedMessage = messagingException.getFailedMessage();
        var failedMessageHeaders = Objects.isNull(failedMessage) ? null : failedMessage.getHeaders();
    
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(messagingException)
                            .copyHeaders(failedMessageHeaders)
                            .build();
    }
```

Comment: Show, please, your `Jms.inboundGateway` configuration and how you handle error.

Comment: Please find my edits in original post, for now (testing purpose) we are sending the `failedMessage` as reply message

Comment: What does your `AppMessageUtil::getFailedMessageAsPayload` do? Because I see that that return of your transformer is `Message<MessagingException>` which might not contain all the required headers from request...

Comment: Please see the edit again, I could see all the required headers like `replyChannel`, `errorChannel` present. Please highlight if anything specific is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you perform the processing of the request message on the same thread, it is blocked on a send and therefore we just re-throw an exception as is:

```
    try {
        doSend(channel, requestMessage, sendTimeout);
    }
    catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        tempReplyChannel.setSendFailed(true);
        throw ex;
    }
```

And as you see we mark that `tempReplyChannel` as failed on a `send` operation.
So, the `replyChannel` header correlated with that `mqReplyChannel` is out of use. If you get rid of it at all, then everything is OK. But you also cannot reply back an `Exception` since the framework treats it as an error to re-throw back to the listener container:

```
    if (errorFlowReply != null && errorFlowReply.getPayload() instanceof Throwable) {
        rethrow((Throwable) errorFlowReply.getPayload(), "error flow returned an Error Message");
    }
```

So, here is a solution:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So75249125Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So75249125Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow jmsFlow(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlow.from(Jms.inboundGateway(connectionFactory)
                        .requestDestination("testDestination")
                        .errorChannel("appErrorChannel"))
                .transform(payload -> {
                    throw new RuntimeException("intentional");
                })
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow errorFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlow.from("appErrorChannel")
                .transform(So75249125Application::getFailedMessageAsPayload)
                .get();
    }

    public static Message<String> getFailedMessageAsPayload(MessagingException messagingException) {
        var failedMessage = messagingException.getFailedMessage();
        var failedMessageHeaders = failedMessage.getHeaders();

        return MessageBuilder.withPayload("failed")
                .copyHeaders(failedMessageHeaders)
                .build();
    }

}
```

and unit test:

```
@SpringBootTest
class So75249125ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Test
    void errorFlowRepliesCorrectly() throws JMSException {
        Message reply = this.jmsTemplate.sendAndReceive("testDestination", session -> session.createTextMessage("test"));
        assertThat(reply.getBody(String.class)).isEqualTo("failed");
    }

}
```

Or even better like this:

```
public static String getFailedMessageAsPayload(MessagingException messagingException) {
    var failedMessage = messagingException.getFailedMessage();
    return "Request for '" + failedMessage.getPayload() + "' has failed";
}
```

and this test:

```
@Test
void errorFlowRepliesCorrectly() throws JMSException {
    String testData = "test";
    Message reply = this.jmsTemplate.sendAndReceive("testDestination", session -> session.createTextMessage(testData));
    assertThat(reply.getBody(String.class)).isEqualTo("Request for '" + testData + "' has failed");
}
```

Comment: Thanqqq, it worked now. To summarize, since the Jms message was processed on the same thread it was not necessary to pull the headers from the failedMessage. As well, the choice to return an `Exception` message was bad. As well, need not use a `replyChannel` unless the response has to be consumed by multiple like in pub-sub

Comment: Well, you can pull those headers from a `failedMessage`, but only if you return the whole `Message` object from the transformer. Otherwise the framework takes care about that for us. The problem was really about that `.replyChannel(mqReplyChannel)` where we tried to send in the end. The real problem was that you have returned an `Exception` as a reply from the error flow. In this case the framework treats such a reply as an error to re-throw.

Comment: Another problem was with a `.copyHeaders(failedMessage.getHeaders())`. I think this is an interesting use-case we need to take into account when we are going to revise headers for `ErrorMessage`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3984

Comment: Thanq, it has been a very great experience working on Spring Integration the last 6 months. Honestly, without a strong SO and GH support, we would have been lost somewhere in the journey. We do think everything with Spring Integration as a solution, little addicted :)

Comment: Another observation, I also need to send a copy of the `exceptionMessage` to another `global errorChannel` that takes care of emailing. Seeing the same error with `publishSubscribe()`. Please see my edit

Comment: We probably need to see what you are doing in that global error handler. I just added a plain `.log(LoggingHandler.Level.ERROR, "global.error")` and see an error in logs and reply for JMS request.

Comment: The global error handler, does do `.<MessagingException, Message<MessagingException>> transform(MessageUtil::getFailedMessageAsPayload)` and ends on a `NullChannel` once email is sent. It is a `DirectChannel`, hence it might be effecting the same thread

Comment: You don't need a `nullChannel` if you use just `handle(Mail.outboundAdapter())` in the end of flow.

Comment: Please try `.<String> log(DEBUG, m -> "Error Response: " + m.getPayload() + ", Headers: " + m.getHeaders())` after the `transformer`, this time the message did not reach the Jms Queue alone, no error in logs and it reaches the JMS Queue if the `log` statement is removed

Comment: That's correct for an older Spring Integration version. Try to add a `bridge()` after that `log()`. See more info in the Migration Guide: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-5.x-to-6.0-Migration-Guide#log-at-the-end-of-a-flow